# Creating multiple objects with a single call

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to add multiple objects in my model named cart using django REST framework. The user will send mutiple sets of data of cart object to the CartAddSerializer and the serializer will add the rows in the database one by one. My code progress so far is as follows:

models.py:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    sh_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    unique_together = ["user", "product"]
```

serializer.py:

```
class CartAddSerializer(ModelSerializer):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
    super(CartAddSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Cart
    fields = ['user', 'product', 'sh_price', 'quantity', 'date_added']
    extra_kwargs = {'date_added': {'read_only': True},
                    'sh_price': {'read_only': True},}

def create(self, data):
    product_data = data.get('product' or None)
    print(product_data)
    print(product_data.id)
    product_price = ProductPrice.objects.get(product=product_data)
    print(product_price)
    print(product_price.sh_price)
    return Cart.objects.create(sh_price=product_price.sh_price, **data)
```

views.py:

```
class CartAddAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartAddSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'id'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=self.kwargs['id'])
            print(cart)
            serializer = CartDetailSerializer(cart, many=True, context={'request': request})
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return Response({"status": "failed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Please make sure that your question is clear and specific. Writing the cart is a bit too vague.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I made some changes @Linovia

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to send multiple sets of data to be added in the database.
There will be a list of cart objects that will be sent to CartAddSerializer via the CartAddAPIView that will insert data into the database.

Comment: According to your model, cart can have only one project. Is it right?

Comment: For now I can add cart objects one at a time

Answer (score 0):

generally,  ListCreateAPIView is mixined by GenericAPIView, ListModelMixin, CreateModelMixin, so it doesn't provide a create list objects function. it's funny ～ [listcreateapiview](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview)

this is an example, and you should post it with json-format data.

```
[
    {
        "user": 1,
        "product": 2,
        "sh_price": 10,
        "quantity": 3,
     },
    {
        another object
    },
    ...
]


def post(self, request):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True, context={'request': request})  #many=True
    serializer.is_valid() #validate request.data
    serializer.save()     #save every object of request.data
```

Comment: Well there must be some way I can serialize a list of objects?

Comment: If you want to create a list of objects, you have to write this view yourself. [have a look at this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer). By the way, you needn't to custom a list serializer, just pass multi object data which you want to create to CartAddSerializer, then call serializer.save().

Comment: Can you show me an example for the latter option you mentioned in your comment?